# STA thread context for WCF duplex proxy callback

Tags: c#

I have an assembly that runs under an STA thread within a sandbox from a third party, within this thread i have created a duplex WCF client that needs to execute methods on the original STA thread.

The current implementation works fine, within the Duplex callback I obtain the synchronization context of the STA thread as follows and use it to Post back to the STA thread:

```
private readonly SynchronizationContext _syncContext = AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext;
```

This all runs within a WinForm initialised in the STA thread, great... but I need to move the WCF duplex proxy so it instead runs under a class instance within the main STA thread. When I remove the winform I end up getting a completely new thread from the above SynchronizationContext.

To clarify:

Winforms:

- Start WCF Duplex Proxy on STA thread - ManagedThreadId = 1
- Receive duplex callback from server - ManagedThreadId = 5
- Post to callback event method using AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext - ManagedThreadId = 1

Without WinForm (class instance):-

- Start WCF Duplex Proxy on STA thread - ManagedThreadId = 1
- Receive duplex callback from server - ManagedThreadId = 6
- Post to callback event method using AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext - ManagedThreadId = 11

Executing on thread 11 instead of 1 means my methods fail to execute properly within the sandbox, there is no difference in the code between variants other than that one runs under a winform. Does anyone know how i can keep the duplex callback method execution in the main STA thread without using the winform?

Comment: Can you use the `Dispatcher` class? Also, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others, that shows how you get the correct thread id when using winforms and how you get the wrong thread id when you don't use winforms.

Comment: An minimal example would be very large, it would have to include the client and server components. I agree that most issues should have the basic example to aid with investigation but unfortunately it's not easily possible here. I'll have to test dispatching the callback method call to ManagedThreadId 1 but the main issue is that I'm really unsure why there is such a difference between running it a winform and in a standard class. The only time the threadID changes in the winform is when the call from the server is received, i then post it back to threadid 1's sync context.

Comment: In the standard class even the WCF client instance has a seperate threadid, followed by a seperate id for the callback and then for the method executed by posting back to the executing threads sync context. It's like the winform binds everything to the UI thread...i might need to replicate that in the standard class but I'm unsure how, any ideas?